# PHP OCI BIND-IN & BIND-OUT ISSUE

Tags: php, oracle-call-interface

I have a PHP database application and I am getting an error while trying to bind-in and bind-out string variables using OCI functions. If the bind size is too large, the values get bound-in to the wrong database fields (no Oracle, PHP, or OCI error; data just ends up in the wrong columns). I have written the following code that determines the largest bind size value I can use on each server I use. It works, but I don't understand why there is such a limit. Is it related to a PHP .INI parameter? The limit is different on different servers (range from 1333 to 4000) which are all running the same PHP and Oracle versions. I have checked everywhere I can think of but can't come up with an answer. I am running Zend Studio 7.2.1 and Oracle 11/g. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
//  Determine value of MAXBINDSIZE. Note a database connection has already been established in "$conn".
$backupBy = "CAC";
$backupStatus = "Success";
$mx = 8000;//largest reasonable value (for me).
$my = $mx / 2;
$maxBindSize = 1000;//smallest reasonable value (for me).
$i = 0;
while ($my > 1)
{
  $name = "TEST-" . $mx;
  $query = "INSERT INTO DB_INFO (NAME, BACKUP_BY, BACKUP_STATUS)
           VALUES ('{$name}', :BACKUPBY, :BACKUPSTATUS) RETURNING NAME INTO :NAME";
  if ($q = oci_parse($conn, $query))
    if (oci_bind_by_name($q, ":BACKUPBY", $backupBy, $mx))
      if ( oci_bind_by_name($q, ":BACKUPSTATUS", $backupStatus, $mx))
        if ( oci_bind_by_name($q, ":NAME", $name, $mx))
          if (oci_execute($q))
          {
             $query = "select * from db_info where name='{$name}'";//'read back what we just wrote...
             if (($q = oci_parse($conn, $query)) && oci_execute($q)) $row = oci_fetch_array($q);
           }
  if (!isset($row["BACKUP_BY"]) || ($row["BACKUP_BY"] != "{$backupBy}") || ($row["BACKUP_STATUS"] != "{$backupStatus}"))
    $mx = $mx - $my;//no go, reduce max bind size
  else
  {
    $maxBindSize = $mx; //save last successful value.
    $mx = $mx + $my;
  }
  unset($row);
  $my = intval($my / 2);
  $i++;
  if (($mx < 1000) ||($mx > 8000) || ($i > 16)) $my = 0;//paranoia
}
//  Cleanup table, delete bogus entries and save largest successful value for next time.
$query = "delete from db_info where substr(name,1,4) = 'TEST'";
if ($q = oci_parse($conn, $query)) oci_execute($q);
$_SESSION["MAXBINDSIZE"] = $maxBindSize;
//
```

Comment: I know It's late, but oci_bind_by_name you can pass int $max_length = -1, It will use the maximum of the server that It's running.